# Which one is a better term: a men-hater, a men hater or a man hater?

Tags: meaning, nouns, terminology, hyphenation

Which one is a better term to describe a person who has a hatred towards men: a **men-hater**, a **men hater** or a **man hater**?

In the Corpus of Contemporary American English there are such combinations like "Trump hater", "Obama hater", "Hillary Clinton hater", "woman hater", "Jew hater", "cop hater", "cat hater", "dog hater", "lady hater", "white hater", "man hater".

What bewilders me: could not the unhyphenated version be misinterpreted as a two noun combination in which the first noun describes the second, as in "table lamp", that is as "man who hates", not as "somebody who hates men"?

And which is a better way to describe the phenomenon: a **men-hate**, a **men hate**, a **man hate**?
I do not want to use the word "misandry" as few people would understand what it means.

Comment: You forgot a "hater of men" and by "man" do you mean the male gender or mankind in general?

Comment: [Misandrist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misandry)

Comment: What makes you think few people would understand _misandry_? It’s a perfectly normal word which I would expect most people to understand.

Comment: By man I mean male.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **man-hater** would be the best way or most appropriate to express such.  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/113450?redirectedFrom=man-hater&) Of note, the OED uses the hyphen.

> A hater of the male sex.

The Free Dictionary also uses the hyphen:

> man-hater: someone, esp a woman, who dislikes or hates men

As in:

> 1988   A. Lurie Truth about Lorin Jones   "Polly was always a
>   man-hater".

Answer (score 0):

All the examples you found use a singular for the first part, even when semantically the hating refers to multiple individuals. Therefore, I would suggest that any option starting with the plural *men* would be out, leaving only a single option from your three choices as correct.

As for the second part of your question, in *man hater*, the first part does describe the second: it is a *hater* of *man*. Your alternative interpretation (a man who hates) would actually make the *second* part describe the *first* one, which is not very common. So I don't think there will be any confusion.

On the other hand, the hyphen is not forbidden, and as @lbf notes, the OED includes the hyphen. But then the correct option would be *man-hater*, which is for some reason not in your original choices...

Comment: If used without a hyphen, say, we take a similar sentence: "Andy is a man driver" - is it clear that Andy is a person who drives men, or Andy is a man who is a driver?

Comment: Yes, in that case Andy is a driver of men. The other interpretation is not intuitive, because that would be called a _male driver_. A _truck driver_ is never a truck that drives, is it?

Comment: I agree. But does hyphenation make it more definite? Is a sentence "Andy is a male hater" more ambiguous than "Andy is a male-hater"?

Comment: How did we get from man hater to male hater? Personally, the hyphen between two nouns brings to mind constructions like singer-songwriter. If I read man-hater in the same way as singer-songwriter, then it describes someone who is a man and who hates, which in the right context could mean the exact opposite from man hater.

Comment: That is an interesting point. I am trying to understand it myself. On the one hand, all versions in the dictionaries are hyphenated. On the other hand, all versions in the Corpus of Contemporary American English are unhyphenated. So, which one is the better? Has to be a rule that regulates that. The difference between "man hater" and "male hater", in my view, is that the word "male" can function both as a noun and as an adjective. And that is why the sentence "Andy is a male hater" seems ambiguous to me. And hyphenation would remove that ambiguity, wouldn't it?